# Pkcs11 x509 chain verification

Tags: x509, verify, pkcs#11, hsm

I am currently implementing a secure channel setup with an HSM.
The protocol is proprietary but uses standard crypto mechanisms (rsa sha)

At a securre channel setup we receive a stack of certificates, with the last one 
the remote device personal cert.
This chain must be validated, in high level languages, no problem.
But I could not find any example how this is done with the pkcs11 interface.
I have the impression there is **no** cert chain verification method in pkcs11?
Must I disect every cert and calculate the signature with the basic pkcs11 
functions? And this is not very secure, you would want to pass the whole stack to a HSM, which reports back: OK or NOT. In case of OK the public key of the (in our case) device cert could be used to crypt a random channel key, etc etc.

So the question is , how is this normally done with pkcs11?

Answer (score 1):

X.509 certificate chain validation is high level operation which is not directly supported in rather low-level PKCS#11 API (same goes for certificate signing request generation, certificate issuance etc.). You will need to use some other general purpose cryptographic library such as OpenSSL for that.

Comment: As far as i can see now, end-2-end security terminating in the HSM 
will not be possible. If the server software (which is using the hsm) is compromised then a secure channel could be created with a malicious remote party.

Comment: @RobF Well this is not possible with PKCS#11 but most HSM vendors allow you to run arbitrary code inside HSM so you might be able to modify your server software to execute in secure environment provided by the device. Of course in such case you will still need to put a lot of trust in your HSM vendor.